# How to get the Dynamic values of the Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a code where the button and title are in same div container like this:

```
<div class="cmpl-teaserd__content">
        <div class="cmpl-teaserd__pretitle">Featured Sample Title</div>        
    <div class="cmpl-teaserd__title wow animated" style="visibility: visible;">
        <h2><b>Borcher</b> <span style="font-weight: normal;">Collection</span></h2>
    </div>      
    <div class="cmpl-teaserd__description">
        <p>Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text</p>
    </div>        
    <div class="cmpl-teaserd__action-container">        
    <a class="cmpl-teaserd__action-link" href="#.html" target="_self" title="">View Collection</a>
 </div>
```

Am using the Code like this:

```
$(document).on("click","a.cmpl-teaserd__action-link",function(){
    console.log("Title:" + $(this).text() + " Link Clicked");
  
});
```

**Requirement:**
I want to get the **Title1**`(div.cmpl-teaserd__pretitle)` & **Title2**`(div.cmpl-teaserd__title wow animated)` of the container once the **link**`(a.cmpl-teaserd__action-link)` got clicked.

Kindly provide your feedback to get the value

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the divs inside the selected div and then maintain a counter to print just the div you want to print. It can be better implemented.
this might help.

```
    $(document).on("click","a.cmpl-teaserd__action-link",function(){
        var count = 1;
        $('div.cmpl-teaserd__content div').each (function (count) {
            count++;
            if(count<3){
                console.log("Title"+count +" "+  $(this).attr('class'));
            }
        });
  
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried this code, but this is not working.

Comment: Could you post what is that error you are getting.